# Uninitialized Constant in rails 3 in_place_edit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, edit-in-place

I want to edit the name of my object temp_thing in place by using the in_place_editor_field.

In my view I use the following code for my object @temp_thing:

```
<%= in_place_editor_field :temp_thing, :name %>
```

now when changing the name and clicking edit I get the following error

```
Uninitialized constant TempThing
```

My Model is defined in the class temp_thing.rb

```
class Test::TempThing < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Someone an idea? What tests can give me more hints? I used firebug for debugging.

Comment: could it be because of the namespaced model?

Answer (score 0):

It must be something because the model is namespaced... Have you tried the following?

```
<%= in_place_editor_field 'Test::TempThing', :name %>
```